# How to create scheduler in c# to sync SharePoint online list to on premise

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Can anyone help me with any code sample which i can refer for my c# scheduler to create a exe which will read data from sharepoint online and create item in sharepoint on premise.
From flow we can achieve this using connection gateway but i have to write exe in c# console application which will run in every hour

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSOM in console application. You will need to add below dlls in Console application.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
```

For reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code